# Can i dynamically make part of text in textblock bold?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

For example, I want a list of textblock binded to a observableCollection to be like this:

1. A**B**C
2. **B**CF
3. **B**OY
4. **B**OOK
5. A**B**SOR**B**
6. **B**EFORE

Comment: It is very complicated to do this. It is achievable. Just create textblock runtime and also define "RUN" for each character and make bold particular RUM block. I suggest not to do that.

Comment: Are you implementing any search functionality where character written in searchbox should be highlighted into the collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Flow document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/flow-document-overview) in C#, use FlowDocument.FontWeight

[image]

```
<FlowDocumentReader>
  <FlowDocument
    FontFamily="Century Gothic"
    FontSize="12"
    FontStretch="UltraExpanded"
    FontStyle="Italic"
    FontWeight="UltraBold"
  >
    <Paragraph>
      Any font settings on this paragraph would override the font settings
      for the FlowDocument.
    </Paragraph>
  </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentReader>

FlowDocument flowDoc = new FlowDocument(new Paragraph(new Run("A bit of text content...")));
// Set the desired column gap to 10 device independend pixels.
flowDoc.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Century Gothic");
flowDoc.FontSize = 12.0;
flowDoc.FontStretch = FontStretches.UltraExpanded;
flowDoc.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
flowDoc.FontWeight = FontWeights.UltraBold;
```

Another way is to use **Run** Tag, as @Gaurang recommends:

```
public SectionExample()
{

    // Create three paragraphs
    Paragraph myParagraph1 = new Paragraph(new Run("Paragraph 1"));
    Paragraph myParagraph2 = new Paragraph(new Run("Paragraph 2"));
    Paragraph myParagraph3 = new Paragraph(new Run("Paragraph 3"));

    // Create a Section and add the three paragraphs to it.
    Section mySection = new Section();
    mySection.Background = Brushes.Red;

    mySection.Blocks.Add(myParagraph1);
    mySection.Blocks.Add(myParagraph2);
    mySection.Blocks.Add(myParagraph3);

    // Create a FlowDocument and add the section to it.
    FlowDocument myFlowDocument = new FlowDocument();
    myFlowDocument.Blocks.Add(mySection);

    this.Content = myFlowDocument;
}
```